# Global objects are inherently unsafe?

Tags: c++

I know that the order of initialization of static variables defined in different translation units (e.g. different cpp/lib/dll/so files) is undefined. Does it mean that the behavior of following program is not well defined?

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> v;

int main()
{
    v.push_back(1);
}
```

EDIT: Here I used STL vector as an example. But it could be an object of any other "3rd party" class. As such we wouldn't know if that object initialized via some other global variable. This means that in C++ it not safe to create even a single global object with nontrivial constructor.  Right?

Comment: If your global variable's construction does not depend on any other global variables, it's safe.

Comment: No, the order is *unspecified*, meaning that you can't rely on them being initialised in any specific order. If you write code that relies on the order, you may (or may not) cause undefined behaviour. Note that the order *within* a translation unit, such as yours, *is* specified.

Comment: i changed _undefined_ to _not well defined_

Comment: Given that a C++ programs are intended to be implemented in multiple translation units it would be considered a *bug* in any 3rd party library that produced undefined behaviour as a result of it failing to work across multiple translation units.

Comment: **ADD:** Libraries that have global dependencies (eg. MySql C API) might require that you call an `init()` function before using them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, because when you use v in main, it is perfectly defined. The static initialization phase takes place before you use v in main ...

The problem arise if you use 2 globals in different translation units and there is a dependency between the two. See this [C++ FAQ lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html) for an explanation. The next items in the FAQ explains how to avoid the 'fiasco'.

The problem of static initialization made globals worse in C++ than in any other language. Good library writers know the problem and avoid the static order initialization fiasco. And even if not, if the library is well spread, someone will hit the problem and, I hope, fix it. But 3rd party libs are not always well written, they can be libraries written in your company by an ignorant new to C++ programmer ...

So, yes, it is unsafe, you're right. And in C++ avoid globals even more than in other languages !

Note: Columbo as pointed out that the standard does not not exactly say that v is defined before entering main (see his answer). No practical difference in your instance.

Comment: what if vector implementation uses its own global variable? Then it is possible that v is initialized after that variable.

Comment: @quantum: well, that why one should not use globals :) I think library designer (good one, that is) do not use globals. Anyway if vector use a global then yes, static initialization order fiasco can occur ...

Comment: C++ standard library uses globals, e.g. cout and cin.

Comment: @quantum: no one has said they are good ;) In fact IMHO this is not the best designed thing. Globals like cout are an easy way to access a global service. Singleton are a slightly better way to access global services. The best way is to use dependency injection. But having a global is easier ...

Answer (score 6):

It's specified in [basic.start.init]/4:

> It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a
>   non-local variable with static storage duration is done before the
>   first statement of main. If the initialization is deferred to some
>   point in time after the first statement of main, it shall occur before
>   the first odr-use (3.2) of any function or variable defined in the
>   same translation unit as the variable to be initialized.

It is therefore defined that `v` is initialized before its first use in any function of this translation unit, including `main`. That implies that in this particular program `v` is initialized before the first statement of `main`. 
The [static initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html) occurs when **multiple** variables in **different** translation units depend on their relative order of initialization; The initializations may be indeterminately sequenced with respect to each other, depending on their initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's only one global object being defined, there can be only one ordering of its initialization, and therefore there is no issue.